# Converted PHP query to PDO and now getting no results

Tags: pdo

I had a query working just fine, but after converting it to PDO I am getting the results below instead of my results all laid out in the table. Perhaps it is just a problem with my foreach loop and variables? If I dump $row I get array(0) { }, but I get the results below when I dump $results:

//Original (but not secure) code that worked:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT stories.story_name, stories.category, stories.SID,
wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name FROM stories LEFT JOIN wp_users ON
stories.ID=wp_users.ID where stories.active = 1");
```

//New PDO code not working:

```
$results = $dbh->prepare("select 
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
FROM stories
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE stories.active=1");

$results->execute();
$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo var_dump($results);

if ($row) {
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><b>Topic</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Category</b></td>';
echo '<td><b>Last User</b></td>';
echo '</tr>';
foreach ($row as $result) {

echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>site</td>";
echo '<td>$row->category; '</td>';
echo "<td>display_name</a></td>";
}
echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

//Results on page:

```
object(PDOStatement)#76 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(203) “select
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
FROM stories
LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE stories.active=1″
}
```

Comment: Uh... what happens if you comment all your bindparams? You don't have any variables to replace. I'm puzzled that you didn't got an error complaining about that.

Comment: @amenadiel Where/how am I commenting bindparams? I don't see any //comments. I copied and pasted this query from another page where it worked as is but I had to change a few variables here and wonder if that's what is causing the lack of results?

Comment: I'm asking you to comment or remove every bindparam line, because your query doesn't contain any variables. You can execute right after preparing the query.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Well, I just removed the bindparams and same thing. Just no results, no errors. I do need the bindparams ultimately for security right?

Comment: @amenadiel Oh--I am getting results if I var_dump($results) and not row. But results also spitting back the select statement so it looks like this: object(PDOStatement)#76 (1) {
["queryString"]=>
string(203) “select
wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name, ...

Comment: Funny. I'm on the cellphone now so I cannot test it myself, but it's still progress whatsoever :)

Comment: Bind params doesn't help you if you don't specify parameters in your query...and this query isn't accepting user input, so no risk of sql injection...

Comment: Right-thanks. Well, it is select statement, so to be double sure I can go back and add the params I forgot to bind after. But for now just trying to get it to work without the binds. I amended my original post for updated code and results.

Comment: @Justin E of course :)

Answer (score 1):

kindly remove those `bindParam` part. and just remain with this part because you have not passed any parameters in your prepared statement.

```
$results = $dbh->query("
select wp_users.ID,
wp_users.display_name,
stories.SID,
stories.story_name,
stories.category,
FROM storiesLEFT     
JOIN wp_users 
ON 
stories.ID=wp_users.ID
WHERE 
stories.active=1
");

$row = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**EDIT**: You seem to have gotten mixed up on the way. This is how you should have your table

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Topic </th>
  <th>Category</th>
  <th>Last User</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($row as data) { ?>
  <td><?php echo $data['story_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['category']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['display_name']; ?></td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

You have these issue to address:

1. When you use `$row = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`, you fetch rows as $row['foobar'] (array  with foobar being the key) and not $row->foobar. The later is meant for fetching data as object `$row = fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`
2. You don't echo out HTML. Check these [PHP Best Practices (especially no. 5)](http://thisinterestsme.com/php-best-practises/).

Comment: @jaw When you dump, $row what do you get?

Comment: If I dump $row I get array(0) {
}

Comment: Try adding: `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` after you instantiate your pdo object. This will throw an exception if there is an error in the query.

Comment: That yields a ton of errors! Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM stories LEFT JOIN wp_users ON stories.ID=wp_users.ID WHERE stories.active' at line 7

Comment: Also: #2 [internal function]: PHPPC::handle_extra_shortcode('<?php ????$user...') #3 plugin.php(173): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 post-template.php(166): apply_filters('the_content', '<?php ????$user...')

Comment: So you have a sql error in your query. Likely on your ID field. Try escaping all table names, and column names with `. Not sure about the second error. Looks like there is maybe PHP tags inside of php tags??? I can't help more without the code.

Comment: No luck. I'll sleep on it. You can see the original PHP code in my original post. I don't know what I missing as it appears to me that I rewrote everything OK in PDO format...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

after you instantiate your pdo object. This will throw an exception if there is an error in the query.

It is very likely that PDO is suppressing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Got it...It was the commma after stories.category in my SQL statement causing all the chaos! Just needed it to read stories.category FROM stories -- with no comma. Thanks all!